# If a finite set of rational numbers sums to one, does one of the rationals have a denominator equal to the LCM of all the denominators?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fractions, rational-numbers

I was experimenting with an algorithm for generating random numbers from a discrete distribution and came across an interesting observation.  Suppose that you have any finite set of rational numbers *in simplest form* that sums to one, such as

$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{6}$

$\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{11}{20}$

$\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3}$

I noticed that in each case, there is some fraction in each sum whose denominator is the least common multiple of all the denominators collectively.  In the first example, $6 = LCM(2, 3, 6)$; in the second, $20 = LCM(4, 5, 20)$; in the third, $3 = LCM(3, 3, 3)$.

In all of the examples I've tried, this pattern occurs, but I'm not sure if this is just a coincidence or not.  I've attempted to prove that this is true, but I can't make much progress on it.

Am I completely wrong that one of the fractions must have a denominator that's the LCM of the denominators?  Or is there a proof that might help shed light on why this is?

Thanks!

Comment: Take the second one for instance, it can also be written as:$\frac{4}{16}+\frac{5}{25}+\frac{11}{20}$. So it's only true when the fraction can't be simplified any further.

Comment: @Raskolnikov- Ah yes, thanks for pointing that out.  I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: 1/15+1/10+5/6 perhaps?

Comment: @Lopsy- D'oh!  Thanks for pointing that out!  If you promote that to an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: Sure, done! Interestingly enough, I might remember an old IMOSL problem that asked something similar: given any set of arithmetic sequences on the integers, such that every integer is in exactly one sequence, prove that the period of at least one of the sequences is equal to the the lcm of all the periods. I'll be thinking about that question too - this one is true, unless of course I remembered it wrong.

Comment: @templatetypedef I am happy that you care for math.SE by offering to accept Lopsy's Answer and make one less question for the site and reward Lopsy for the time he has spent.

Comment: I think the following weaker version is true: If n irreducible positive fractions add to one, and $n-1$ denominators are pairwise relatively prime, than the remaining denominator is their product...

Comment: @N.S. vacuously true because such thing does not exist.

Comment: Your third example is not the sum of a set of numbers, since the same number appears three times. It seems what you mean is a sum of several rational numbers?

Comment: @ChaoXu $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{6}=1$ and $2$ and $3$ are relatively prime....Also $\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{mn-m-n}{mn}$ would work...

Comment: @N.S. oh sorry, I thought you meant n denominators. and yes that would be true. It follows from the answer for http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95720/bound-on-lcm-of-denominators-of-rational-numbers-that-sum-to-1/98903

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not always true: for example,

$\frac{1}{15}+\frac{1}{10}+\frac{5}{6}=1$

is a counterexample.

Comment: It's also not necessarily true even if all the numerators equal 1. See http://www.math.ubc.ca/~gerg/papers/downloads/recsum6.pdf for a particularly egregious counterexample.

Comment: @GregMartin your tax dollars at work!